# Why are ordinal numbers used to express fractions?

Tags: etymology, numbers, phrase-origin

For fractional numbers other than n/2 and n/4 (which can also be expressed as n fourth/s), such as 1/3 (one third) and 7/10 (seven tenths), the denominator is expressed in the ordinal form of the number.

An [explanation](https://qr.ae/TSJVhJ) given on Quora is that it comes from "'a fourth part of a whole' (or, in general, ' part of a whole') which was a turn of speech that communicated clearly enough that you divided the whole into four (or n) parts and then you only took one of them." However this is unsourced.

French uses the same system but I did not find any source on any potential connection, and I have no idea where the French got the way of expression from.

Comment: Uh, "half" isn't an ordinal number.

Comment: @HotLicks Well I am interested to know why *in general* fractions can be expressed by ordinal numbers. And if *second* wasn't a time unit it could perhaps replace *half* in some cases like *fourth* did to *quarter*.

Comment: Actually, "second" is the second minute time unit.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with English grammar or usage, or are we taking about a cross-language convention of mathematics?

Comment: Note that "half" originally meant "part" (not necessarily equal parts), and there could be three halves of a potato.  So the ordinal terminology arose as advancing society needed more precision.

Comment: It's not ordinal. We don't use ordinal numbers to describe fractions. That is, you'd never ask for "the first half", "the third quarter", or "the seventh tenth" unless the divisions were cardinal in nature and marked as such.

Comment: @RMac I am specifically interested in an explanation on why English expresses fractions this way. It could have come from a cross-language convention (but this certainly is not univeral to all languages) and a sourced answer indicating the language of origin and/or intermediate languages would be a good answer to me.

Comment: @RMac I do not quite understand your second comment. I will edit my question to make it more clear that my question is about the denominator part of a ratio; or did you mean that the *tenth* in seven tenths (7/10) is not an ordinal number but just happened to be constructed in the same way as an ordinal number?

Comment: I think there's an interesting question here, but why do you exclude n/4? 3/4 is "three fourths" and 1/4 is "one fourth" ... Don't get confused because "quarter" and "fourth" are synonyms.

Comment: @Robusto Although personally I also prefer n fourth(s) for n/4, I was trying to avoid people commenting that quarter isn't an ordinal.

Comment: @zhantongz An ordinal number is a number which specifies an element's position in a series. Fractions generally are not series but rather sets, and the set is not ordered. Therefore, no ordinal numbers. So yes, I'm telling you exactly that: construction is the same but these are not ordinal numbers. And this has nothing to do with English. See metric for a simple example, e.g., centimeter, decimeter, nanometer, etc.

Comment: Note also that 3/32 is "three thirty-seconds" (the "half/halves" only applies in n/2 situations). I suspect that we use what appear to be ordinals in English fractions, they probably come from phrases like "the fourth part of *n*," where *n* is any divisible object or quantity. You've made me curious about this as well.

Comment: @RMac My question would then be why English constructs the denominator in a fractional number the same way, with a couple exceptions, as it constructs ordinal numbers, or vice-versa.

Comment: And why aren't the ordinals *oneth, tooth, threeth, fourth, fiveth*?

Comment: @HotLicks It's common to have different rules for different ranges of numbers. E.g. eleven and twelve aren't oneteen and twoteen, and the teens aren't tenty-something.

Comment: Just a thought... I grew up (in the 1950s in NZ) and remember it as "three thirty-secondth" or "three thirty-sec'nths" or sometimes "three thirty-two" when people spoke (I first remember this with spanner sizes). "Three thirty-seconds" sounded wrong to my ears when I first heard it some years later. The workshop had Kiwi and English and Scottish people working in it. 
I think it's possible that different dialects had slightly different ways of expressing fractions and over the last century or so of mathematics being taught in schools the language has become standardised to what we know now.

Comment: @Robusto: And American football really confuses things when idenfying which ordinal piece of a fraction is being discussed: ie. The game was quartered. This is the fourth quarter.)

Answer (score 3):

All quotes from OED (on line - subscription)

> **th, suffix2**
>
> Pronunciation: Primary stress is retained by the usual stressed syllable of the preceding element; see e.g. hundredth adj. and n.
>
> [Used for] Forming ordinal numbers; in modern literary English used with all simple numbers from fourth onward; representing Old English -þa, -þe, or -oða, -oðe, used with all ordinals except fífta, sixta, ellefta, twelfta, which had the ending -ta, -te; in Scottish, northern English, and many midland dialects the latter, in form -t, is used with all simple numerals after third (fourt, fift, sixt, sevent, tent, hundert, etc.). In Kentish and Old Northumbrian those from seventh to tenth had formerly the ending -da, -de. All these variations, -th, -t, -d, represent an original Indo-European -tos (cf. Greek πέμπ-τος, Latin quin-tus), understood to be identical with one of the suffixes of the superlative degree. In Old English fífta, sixta, the original t was retained, being protected by the preceding consonant; the -þa and -da were due to the position of the stress accent, according to Verner's Law.

*Note: The ordinals from twentieth to ninetieth have -eth, Old English -oða, -oðe. In compound numerals -th is added only to the last, as 1/ 1345, the one thousand three hundred and forty-fifth part; in his one-and-twentieth year.*

Taking the example pf One hundred", hundredth, is both an adjective and a noun:

> Etymology: < hundred n. and adj. + -th suffix2...
>
> The ordinal numeral corresponding to the cardinal numeral hundred n. and adj.
>
> A. adj. **1. Coming last in order of a hundred successive individuals.**
>
> 1630   M. Drayton Noahs Floud in Muses Elizium 115   On the six hundred yeere of that iust man The second month, the seuenteenth day began, That horrid Deluge.
>
> 1841   W. Spalding Italy & Ital. Islands I. 103   Extending to the hundredth milestone.
>
> **2.   hundredth part  n. one of a hundred equal parts into which a whole is or may be divided.**
>
> a1300   Cursor Mundi 23140   Þe hundret [Gött. hundreth, F. hundre, Tr. hundride] part i mai noght mele.
>
> 1833   N. Arnott Elements Physics (ed. 5) I. 39   Compressed..so as to have bulk about a hundredth part less.
>
> **B. n. 1. A hundredth part.**
>
> 1774   C. J. Phipps Voy. N. Pole 124   Divided..by a Vernier division into hundredths of an inch.
>
> 1861   J. S. Mill Utilitarianism ii. 26   Ninety-nine hundredths of all our actions are done from other motives.

You will see that the fraction/ordinal is used as a noun.